# HTML5 time element

Tags: html

What is the smallest format I can have for the time element for example `hh:mm` or `YYYY-MM-DD` and still be valid for machines to read.

Comment: Smallest as in number of characters? Storage? Time to compare? And what time do you need? Just an hour and minute? Day of the month? Year? Century?

Comment: as in number of character to be valid for machines to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to W3C, the smallest format is **[the time string](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-time-string)**:

> A time consists of a specific time
>   with no time-zone information,
>   consisting of an hour, a minute, a
>   second, and a fraction of a second.
>
> A string is a valid time string
>   representing an hour *hour*, a minute
>   *minute*, and a second *second* if it
>   consists of the following components
>   in the given order:
>
> - Two digits, representing hour, in the
>     range 0 ≤ hour ≤ 23
> - A U+003A COLON
>     character (:)
> - Two digits, representing
>     minute, in the range 0 ≤ minute ≤ 59
> - Optionally (required if second is
>     non-zero):
>
>   - A U+003A COLON character
>       (:)
>   - Two digits, representing the
>       integer part of second, in the range 0
>       ≤ s ≤ 59
>   - Optionally (required if
>       second is not an integer):
>
>     - A 002E FULL
>         STOP character (.)
>     - One or more digits,
>         representing the fractional part of
>         second

So: `HH:MM` is the smallest possible valid string.

Got that piece of documentation via [the time element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) -> [dateTime attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#dom-time-datetime) -> [dateTime attribute value](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#attr-time-datetime) -> [valid date or time string](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-date-string-with-optional-time) -> [valid time string](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-time-string). That's a pretty comprehensive documentation...